# UIButton - Programmatic creation issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uibutton

I am creating a `UIButton` programmatically as below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [paymentsHomeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)]; // paymentsHomeView is added and referenced in IB

    UIButton *paymentButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 41)];
    paymentButton.titleLabel.text = @"Button";
    paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [paymentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.paymentsHomeView addSubview:paymentButton];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) buttonClicked {

    NSLog(@"buttonClicked");
}
```

There is no output for the above code. The button is not created.

Whereas the same works when I create `UITextField`.

Help me out. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: comment this and run it will work paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; and make sure that you are adding your paymentsHomeView to self.view

Comment: also why are you referring to "`paymentsHomeView`" on one line and then "`self. paymentsHomeView`" in another line there in your "`viewDidLoad`" method?

Comment: Always put `[super viewDidLoad];` as the first line in your method. A super call should be the first one unless it is in dealloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**you need to set frame for button after init statement and you need to set title for button in different way**

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Thank you..! Works like charm..!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one my friend..

```
UIButton *paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[paymentButton addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[paymentButton setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 paymentButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.paymentsHomeView addSubview:paymentButton];
```

let me know is it working or not...!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating button here:

```
UIButton *paymentButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 41)];
```

and again on this line you create another button so this overwrite the previous one, so you need to set the frame again:

```
paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

What I suggest do this:

```
 paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[paymentButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 41)];

    paymentButton.titleLabel.text = @"Button";
    [paymentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.paymentsHomeView addSubview:paymentButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have notated some problems here:

```
[paymentsHomeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)]; // paymentsHomeView is added and referenced in IB

UIButton *paymentButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 41)];
paymentButton.titleLabel.text = @"Button";
// You just allocated a paymentButton above. Without ARC it is leaked here:
paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
// Now you have assigned an auto released button to paymentButton. It does not have a frame or text.
[paymentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.paymentsHomeView addSubview:paymentButton];
```

Try this:

```
UIButton *paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
paymentButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 41);
paymentButton.titleLabel.text = @"Button";
[paymentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.paymentsHomeView addSubview:paymentButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Custom Button use bellow code...**

Remove this line

```
paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

and add this line which shows button with black background

```
paymentButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];// set text color which you want
[paymentButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];// set back color which you want
```

**And for RoundRect Button use bellow code**

```
    UIButton *paymentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    paymentButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 41);
    paymentButton.titleLabel.text = @"Button";
    [paymentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.paymentsHomeView addSubview:paymentButton];
    [self.paymentsHomeView bringSubviewToFront:paymentButton];
```